# Index Multiple Columns w/ Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, indexing, multiple-columns

I have a table in a Mysql db that I want to use multicolumn indexing on.  How can I do this in rails w/o using the mysql console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside a migration definition you can do it like this:

`add_index :table_name, [:column1, :column2]`

Comment: Yep, and occassionally the generated name will be too long and you'll need to add a `:name => 'my_index'` option.

Comment: It also takes the :unique option, which will speed up your queries a little bit if appropriate.