# What is an index in migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm reading the online guide of RoR and saw this piece of code for migration.

```
change_table: products do |t|
  #some code here

  t.string :part_number
  t.index :part_number

  #some code here
end
```

What is the index here? Since I already have a string column called part_number, how come it is possible to add another column with the same name but different type?

Comment: For SQL data sources, it maps to `CREATE INDEX` statements ([MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html), [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createindex.html)). This create a `string` column named `:part_number`, then creates an `index` `ON` that column to speed up querying by it.

Comment: if i recall correctly, the index's column name is actually `part_number_index`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's saying that the `part_number` will be used as an index. The column's name is not `part_number`.

Comment: Is index the same as a primary key? And what's the name of the column then?

Comment: no, an index is a way to organize the database so that it's easily searchable.

Comment: i'm not sure, if so, i've never done it, but you can have an index based on multiple columns.

Comment: thinking about it, it would just involved adding another index based on a different column.

Comment: single index based on two columns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825762/index-multiple-columns-w-ruby-on-rails. You would just add another index based on other columns.

Comment: @user1229490 If there are any restrictions on number of indexes, they would be imposed by your database; not by rails. If the database supports multiple indexes per table, and at least most do, then you can create each of them through `t.index` in rails migrations.